# Настройка свича extreme summit 200-24

Tags: свич

Как пробросить вилан и добавить на него порты я разобрался, а вот с доступом через телнет никак и еще первый влан никак не хочет удаляться. Вопросы такие:

1. Как настроить доступ через телнет?
2. Как поменять ip свича не убивая при этом vlan?
3. Как задать логин пароль свичу
4. Какой командой посмотреть какие порты на vlane? sh vlan не помог.
5. И как все таки удалить первый вилан, выдает от такую от ошибочку: *Summit200-24:20 # delete vlan Default ERROR: Cannot delete "Default" vlan*

Answer (score 2):

> 1)Как настроить доступ через телнет?

Судя по мануалу телнет уже вкл. что именно не получается?

> 2)Как поменять ip свича не убивая приэтом vlan? 5)И как все таки удалитьпервый вилан, выдает от такую отошибочку(* Summit200-24:20 # deletevlan Default ERROR: Cannot delete"Default" vlan)

Усли у вас в сети нет vlanа для управления свитчами то удалять его нет смысла

> 3)Как задать логин пароль свичу

config account [admin | user] <username> {encrypted}

> 4)Какой командой посмотреть какиепорты на vlane? sh vlan не помог.

show vlan должно быть  Ports assignedили выкладывайте сюда вывод команды, разберемся.

Comment: sh ports info получилось.и в самом деле telnet уже присутствует там.не могли бы вы еще сказать как присвоить имена портам?

Comment: нужно было удолить ip с влана и поставить другой.. разобрался там просто всесто conf нужно было unconf вписать

Comment: вродебы так config ports <portlist> display-string <string> где string все что угодно

Comment: помогло, спасибо вам большое.и если еще не трудно будет ответить как сбросить на нем все настройки на ноль? контрл+H как да DELL не помогает

Comment: unconfig switch {all}

Comment: ну это в самом свиче, к одному из них я пароль не знаю, как скинуть?

Comment: если свитч не оборудован кнопкой ресет то тока в саппорт с документами хотя я сомневаюсь что ресет поможет

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо за консультацию!!!

Answer (score 0):

дефолтный влан удалять совершенно не стоит.
например, в коммутаторах Cisco он обязательно должен быть, в противном случае поимеете гарантированные косяки в работе. В данный влан объеденены все порты коммутатора.
По поводу пароля: не знаю как в данном коммутаторе, а в Cisco имеется возможность удаления админ-пароля.